# GCP Dataproc version control

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

We work on jupyter notebooks interchangeably between Dataproc and on local computer. Usually, we write and test the code on a smaller sample locally and run it on all of the data in Dataproc. However, the way we are doing it currently is by downloading/uploading the notebooks between Google Cloud Storage and the local computer, which is not optimal for several reasons. We also have a Github repository connected to the folder on the local computer. Is it possible to clone a Github repository to GCS and work with git from there?

We found a workaround using initialization actions when we create a cluster:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create test-init-actions \
    --enable-component-gateway \
    --bucket {bucket-name} \
    --single-node \
    --image-version=2.1.0-RC2-debian11 \
    --optional-components JUPYTER \
    --project {project-name} \
    --initialization-actions=gs://{project-name}/initialization-actions/clone-public-repo.sh
```

Where the content of `clone-public-repo.sh` is just (we'll extend this to a private repository):

```
git clone https://github.com/{user}/{repo-name}
```

This clones the repository to the cluster's local storage and we can use git normally from there. The problem with this approach is that the local changes to the notebooks in Dataproc are not persisted if the cluster is deleted. So we'd always have to commit and push before deleting the cluster. This would result in committing unfinished code just for the sake of persistence and possible loss of progress if a developer forgets to commit and push.

Is there a way that the local changes in the cluster's disk are persisted somewhere else, for example GCS, without manually storing the files there?

Edit: We would like to use git in both ways, for cloning to the cluster and committing the changed code back to the Github repository. Cloning the repository into cluster's local storage allows that, but we run the risk of losing uncommitted changes if the cluster is deleted. On the other hand, mirroring the repository on GCS (using, for example, Github actions) and working with the notebook from there the changes will be persisted on GCS, but we would be unable to commit/push changes back to the Github repository.

Comment: Hi @gregorp, You can enable Github actions on Google Cloud Storage and store the data generated. For more information you can check this [link1](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/admin/github-actions/enabling-github-actions-for-github-enterprise-server/enabling-github-actions-with-google-cloud-storage) and [link2](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/google-cloud-storage-bucket-sync-gcp-gcs). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, thank you for the links. If I understand correctly this only syncs the Github repository to the bucket, but not the other way around? I'm looking for a way to change the notebooks in the cloud and for the changes to persist. If this works the way I understand a push to the repo would overwrite my changes in the bucket? Additionally, I'd still have to manually download the changes to the notebook on cloud and move them to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to enable Github actions on Cloud Storage using the steps mentioned in this [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/admin/github-actions/enabling-github-actions-for-github-enterprise-server/enabling-github-actions-with-google-cloud-storage) . For your requirement to save the changes in Cloud Storage,  ensure it is able to save your checkpoints

- Make sure the GCS is set up correctly to save checkpoints. You can check /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py and make sure that c.GCSContentsManager.bucket_name is present and set with the right bucket. If not present, you need to set it and then from Dataproc Web UI, Kernel > Restart to restart Jupyter from the Jupyter menu.
- Make sure your account has admin/write access to your bucket for which you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly this solution only solves half of the problem -- how to persist changes made on jupyter notebook that is running on Dataproc. We are unable to commit/push the changes made to the notebook in GCS back to the Github repository. Do I understand this correctly?


Maybe an alternative could be cloning the Github repository to the cluster's local storage at cluster creation and setting up [Jupyter savehooks](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html) in the config to copy the file to GCS using `gsutil cp`?

Comment: I updated the original question to be more clear about the second part -- committing the changes back to the Github repository.